# wise payment with laravel

Tags: laravel, wise, transferwise

I have qustion on how to use wise payment in larevel
is there any tutorial or steps to do that because the documentation is not clear about the order of the steps and how to implement it in the most easy way
And Is there way to do the payment using checkout link frome there side not using the apis

Following the documentation

Answer (score -1):

I can share my codes for wise payment. You need `guzzlehttp/guzzle` to make HTTP requests.

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

Store credentials in your .env file:

```
WISE_API_KEY=your_api_key_here
```

Create a Wise Service:

```
namespace App\Services;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class WiseService
{
    protected $client;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->client = new Client([
            'base_uri' => 'https://api.wise.com/', 
            'headers' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer ' . env('WISE_API_KEY'),
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ],
        ]);
    }

    public function getCheckoutUrl($amount, $currency)
{
    $response = $this->client->post('checkout/create', [
        'json' => [
            'amount' => $amount,
            'currency' => $currency,
        ],
    ]);

    $data = json_decode($response->getBody(), true);
    
    return $data['checkout_url'];
}
}
```

In your controller, you can then call this service to get the checkout URL and redirect the user:

```
use App\Services\WiseService;

public function checkout(WiseService $wiseService)
{
    $url = $wiseService->getCheckoutUrl(100, 'USD');  
    return redirect($url);
}
```

After the user completes the payment on Wise's platform, Wise might redirect the user back to your application with some data about the payment. You should have routes and logic to handle these callbacks (webhooks).

Look at Wise documentation and modify codes if needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this is tha same answer that i get from chatgpt and its not helpful because wise dont have checkout/create api or any other api to generate checkout url

Comment: I used these codes in my old project. But you can look this package for wise payment, it would be helpful for you: `https://packagist.org/packages/transferwise/wise-php`